# check if part of textvalue is contained in another textvalue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to confirm that the email was written in the email field ex: `email@test.com` is related to the website written in the website field ex:`www.test.com` so I had to use the Javascript function that slices the website's name after `www.` and check if it exists in the email field.

here are the input forms code and the user JS script :

```js
function owner() {
  var website = document.getElementById(id_website);
  var email = document.getElementById(id_contact_email);
  var y = "www.";
  var website_host = y.slice(y.indexOf(website) + website.length);
  if (email.indexOf(website_host) >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = 'email and website are the same';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="website" maxlength="120" id="id_website">
<input type="email" name="contact_email" onchange="owner();" required="" id="id_contact_email">
<p id="testing">website name here</p>
```

Nothing happens at all when i write, nothing changes or even the function is not triggered .

Comment: I've made a live demo (https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qs61a0gh/) from your posted code (note that the JavaScript from your `<script>` element is in the JavaScript panel); if you open your developer tools you'll note that the script does run, but there is an error. First: correct the errors (so far as you can) and then, if there are still problems, update your question. I'd consider putting this question on hold temporarily while you fix the existing problems that you can solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed the single quotations in `getElementById()` method and you should access the `value` and do further process

```js
function owner() {
  var website = document.getElementById('id_website').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('id_contact_email').value;
  var y = "www.";
  var website_host = y.slice(y.indexOf(website) + website.length);
  if (email.indexOf(website_host) >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = 'email and website are the same';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="website" maxlength="120" id="id_website">
<input type="email" name="contact_email" onchange="owner();" required="" id="id_contact_email">
<p id="testing">website name here</p>
```